# Windows Profile Name is Smiley Face

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles

I am helping my friend with an interesting problem. His Profile Name in Windows is `☺`. Like the path is `C:\Users\☺\Desktop`.

Would this cause any issues with running programs? My friend says he does not remember ever setting the User Name to be a smiley face.

[image]

Comment: This means the name was either using characters can no longer decipher or something happened to cause that to happen/  We need more information.

Comment: `☺` (codepoint  `U+263A`) _White Smiling Face_ should constitute a valid user/account name (as for instance a name of Greek, Cyrillic or Hebrew characters). Compare [Creating User and Group Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx) and [Username](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn965864(v=vs.85).aspx) Microsoft articles.

Comment: @JosefZ: But there have been a lot of issues like Java installer won't even run and all the errors have to do with a file not found in AppData path even though it exists.